# Not able to select text in Edittext in Android on longclick?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to select text in Edittext for showing options of copy,paste but it is not selecting text on long press.

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_extractedText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="@string/st_etHint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

I am using Android studio and build tools version 21.1.2.

Comment: Just a guess, remove this line : android:textIsSelectable="true" , usually an edittext is long clickable by default.

Comment: i removed android:textIsSelectable="true" , but still not working

Comment: Sorry Im on my mobile, cant really test anything; try : android:longClickable="true" but it is usually true by default as far as I know.

Comment: @DanishZia  your code working fine in moto G2 as I tested, Can you explain where do you do longpress (means longpress at written text or somewhere else)?

Comment: i am doing longpress on text.

Comment: it is also working for me if do it in eclipse, but not android studio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is working in my phone i am using micromax untie 2.

You have hint in you edittext so its showing hint not text, Are you testing without typing anything into editText if that so then its just a hint and on doing long press on hint it will just show a paste option or may be dont show anything.

Comment: i am typing into it, can it be because of the i am using ??
Because this always work for me before.

Comment: After typing in edittext are you doing long press in empty area or on the text you have typed? Because if you have long pressed on empty area then it would not do anything. You have to long press on text which you have inputed in edittext field.

Comment: I am long pressing on the text.

Comment: Please remove 'android:inputType="textMultiLine"' and add 'android:singleLine="true"' and check it out whether single line edittext making selection or not.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the color of highlighting background color.

Add this: `android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_red_dark"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_extractedText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="@string/st_etHint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone facing this issue. Just close the keyboard first. while the keyboard is not showing on the display, long press text. It should be work.